# How to get all parent rows where deeply nested children are all of the same type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, Authors, Posts and Comments

[image: Tables look like this]

Is there a way I can select only those authors who have written posts which contain only good comments?

Comment: How to know which author wrote a comment?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am trying to get authors who have written posts which contain only good comments irrespective of who wrote the comments. So basically I want to select authors having posts where all comments of type good.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far to your post.

Comment: What should happen if an author wrote no post? List them or not? And what about authors, where all of their posts have no comment? List them or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use Joins and a Where

```
Select a.id from
Authors a
join posts b on a.id=b.author_id
join comments c on 
c.post_id=b.id
Where c.type='good';
```

Comment: that will get you all authors that have ever written any post that has had at least one good comment.

Comment: Ahh. You are right. Will update answer tomorrow if not already answered.